# I want to add a button in my navigation bar. When clicked, it calls the system method toggleRecentsActivity to open the recent program

Tags: android, navigation, frameworks, android-recents

I have customized the system navigation bar in the Android system layer and want to add a button in my navigation bar. When clicked, it calls the system method toggleRecentsActivity to open the recent program. However, it is not successful because Recents.start is not called. How to solve it?

Clicking the button in the custom system navigation bar can open the page of the most recently opened program running in the background.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.